# Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010, ajaxcontroltoolkit, toolkitscriptmanager

I'm trying to add a ToolkitScriptManager to my page in order to use the AjaxControlToolkit. Here is my code:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestingAjaxWebPartUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="TestingAjax.TestingAjaxWebPart.TestingAjaxWebPartUserControl" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<html>
<body>
<form>
<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" ID="toolkitScriptManager"></cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" 
         TargetControlID="TextBox2"
         ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList"
         ServicePath="TestingAjaxWebPartUserControl.ascx.cs"
         MinimumPrefixLength="2"
         CompletionInterval="1000"
         EnableCaching="true"
         CompletionSetCount="10">
        </cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I load the page it throws an error saying that only one instance of a script manager can be running. I've been working on this problem almost all day and it's driving me nuts. Where could another script manager be and how do I disable it so that my page will load?

Comment: There might be one on the Master page or Web page containing your usercontrol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the asp.net controls and ajax controls inside the form tag.

Comment: @dserver If you are making a user control page, then it may be possible that a script manager exists in the page which calls this user control page.

Comment: yes, this was it. the root page was using a script manager. commenting it out allowed me to use my own. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check your usercontrol you are referring in the page or in the master page if any ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. My usercontrol is not in the master page; it's just in the .ascx page Visual Studio has created for me. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try placing a form tag around everything inside the body...

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" ID="toolkitScriptManager">
        </cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
        ...
    </form>
</body>
```